# Render a fragment of a html in Thymeleaf from an external server

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have my homepage in my spring boot project called `home.html`. I have a pages controller to render this `home.html`. Below is the code of the controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home")
public String goToHome(Model model) {
    return "home";
}
```

In my project `home.html` is inside `webapp/WEB-INF/static/` folder. so the path is `webapp/WEB-INF/static/home.html`

My `home.html` looks like below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
     <title>home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <object th:include="/en/home :: home-body" th:remove="tag"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I have `home.html` file in an external server as follows.

```
<div th:fragment="home-body">
    <p>Welcome to home page</p>
</div>
```

The path to this file is `http://external-server.com/fragments/en/home.html`

What I want to do is to render this `home-body` fragment part fetching from this external server inside the `home.html` residing in spring boot tomcat server.

I added the below Bean as a configuration to fetch this `home-body` fragment. Below is the code for that.

```
@Bean
    public UrlTemplateResolver urlTemplateResolver(){
        UrlTemplateResolver urlTemplateResolver = new UrlTemplateResolver();
        boolean isCmsContentEnable = Boolean.parseBoolean( env.getProperty( ConfigurationConstants.CMS_CONTENT_ENABLE ) );
        if( isCmsContentEnable )
        {
            urlTemplateResolver.setPrefix( "http://external-server.com/fragments/" );
            urlTemplateResolver.setSuffix( ".html" );
            urlTemplateResolver.setCharacterEncoding( "UTF-8" );
            urlTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode( "HTML5" );
            urlTemplateResolver.setCacheable( false );
            urlTemplateResolver.setOrder(10);
        }
        return urlTemplateResolver;
    }
```

Now when I try to go to home page, what happens is instead of rendering the `home-body` fragment inside the `home.html` residing in the spring boot tomcat server, it directly renders the `home.html` residing in the external server.

How can I fix this issue? Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `SpringTemplateEngine` with `thymeleafTemplateResolver` and `urlTemplateResolver` as templateResolvers.

```
   @Bean public ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver()
{
    ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setTemplateEngine( templateEngine() );
    return viewResolver;
}

@Bean public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine()
{
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    Set<ITemplateResolver> templateResolvers = new HashSet();
    templateResolvers.add( thymeleafTemplateResolver() );
    templateResolvers.add( urlTemplateResolver() );
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolvers( templateResolvers );

    return templateEngine;
}

@Bean public SpringResourceTemplateResolver thymeleafTemplateResolver()
{
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix( "/WEB-INF/static/" );
    templateResolver.setSuffix( ".html" );
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode( "HTML5" );
    templateResolver.setOrder( 2 );
    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean public UrlTemplateResolver urlTemplateResolver()
{
    UrlTemplateResolver urlTemplateResolver = new UrlTemplateResolver();
    urlTemplateResolver.setCharacterEncoding( "UTF-8" );
    urlTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode( "HTML5" );
    urlTemplateResolver.setCacheable( false );
    urlTemplateResolver.setOrder( 3 );
    return urlTemplateResolver;
}
```

Then access the external template like this.

```
 <div th:include="http://banner.server.com/myBanner.html :: fragmentName">
```